# Class Cast Exception error in j2ee

Tags: java

I am trying to retrieve record from a particular column in my data base, after writing the `finder` method in the `entitybean`, I am getting error from session bean `Class Cast Exception: java.lang.String cannot be cast to packagename.PaymentsLocal`. Below is the code snippet in my session bean class

```
ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
Collection col = null;
 try{
    col = plh.findByAllSessions();
    Iterator i = col.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()){
       pl = (PaymentsLocal)i.next(); 
       a.add(new paymenthelper( pl.getSession()));
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println("viewing all sessions"+e.getMessage());
  }
 return a;
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code so that it's readable.  Thanks.

Comment: You are trying to cast a String to an PaymentsLocal which isn't possible. Or do you have a real question?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html

Comment: Btw, please avoid using [raw types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it). They are bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines set up an `Iterator<String>` implicitly, since whatever collection you're returning in `plh.findByAllSessions()` is a Collection of Strings.

```
col = plh.findByAllSessions();
Iterator i = col.iterator();
```

Thus this line tried to force a String to a PaymentsLocal object, which is not possible, causing a ClassCastException.

```
pl = (PaymentsLocal)i.next();
```

This is because `i.next()` returns an object of the type of the collection.